# Is there a "compass rose" that is linearly defined by negative and positive?

Tags: momentum, vectors

I see a "What are negative and positive energies" question by Bhavesh but it was in 2015, so please refresh me.

When in momentum, going N,E,S,W etc, you are calculating, do you consider these directions to change the sign of velocity?
Why and/or why not? (just for fun)

Actually though, I'm questioning whether or not S and W can change my velocity sign to a negative, but mostly I'm confused with why it can't.

I understand spacial and quantum directions,  but why can't we theorize? :/ anyway, happy physics,ing.

*is this question so stupid that i need 1000 reputation points to use tags?*
#momentum #velocity #direction #vector #negative

Comment: what is a quantum direction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum is a vector, i.e., it isn't just a number, it has direction. This means that it has *components*, along the $x$ and $y$ axes. (To take your 2D example.) We can write it like this: $(p_x, p_y)$ where $p_x$ is the $x$-component of momentum and $p_y$ is the $y$-component. For each of the two dimensions, a positive and negative end must be picked.

Conventionally, the positive $x$ direction is to the right ("east") and the positive $y$ direction is up ("north"). These are matters of convention, however. An alien species could redevelop physics with a different orientation of axes and all that would happen is that there would be minus signs here and there in their calculations; they should get all the same predictions in their experiments.

Using this convention, a particle which is traveling "east" has momentum which looks like $(1,0)$. A particle traveling "south" has momentum that looks like $(0,-1)$. A particle traveling "northwest" has a momentum which is equally "north" and "west" and so we would say $(1,-1)$. Of course actual momenta will depend on the speed and mass of the particle; these are just what the directions look like.

Comment: it's the "they should get all the same predictions in their experiments", thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The sign of velocity will depend on where you choose your origin and what direction you assume to be positive or negative. For example, I may take the downward direction as positive and the upward negative during projectile motion. It doesn't affect my analysis as long as I take care that signs of all quantities are consistent with my choice of the positive direction.

Another example may be the motion of a car on a straight road going from east to west. If I take the displacement in the west direction to be positive, then my velocity would be positive in the west direction and negative if I move towards the east direction.

Comment: oo, I see, Thank you!